Converting 3d points transformation matrix to a 2d birds eye view transformation matrix?
I have two 3d point clouds and i know the transformation matrix between their points. However, the two point clouds are passed into top view projection where i ignore the z axis coordinates and are converted to grids. I am not allowed to perform the transformation before this happening. So i need to find the transformation matrix between the two point cloud grids knowing that i know the transformation between the two original point clouds.
Can please someone help?

Assuming an affine transformation, the transformation p´=A*p would be:
x´   r_xx r_yx r_zx t_x   x
y´ = r_xy r_yy r_zy t_y * y
z´   r_xz r_yz r_zz t_z   z
1    0    0    0    1     1

If you don't need to know z´, then you can discard the corresponding row in A. However, if you don't know z, then this becomes impossible to solve, unless you know that r_zx and r_zy are zero. In other words, if you don't know the z coordinate, then you can only calculate x´ and y´ if you know that the z-coordinate has no influence on them. A rotation around the z-axis would be such a case.
